# Colours don't show up in diagram

Tags: r, diagrammer

I have code that should render diagrams with few extra colours, but when code in used I don't see any colours

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c( "Cat", "Dog", "Bird"),
 col2 = c( "Feline", "Canis", "Avis"), 
 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

uniquenodes <- unique(c(df$col1, df$col2))

library(DiagrammeR)

cols <- setNames(rep("green", length(uniquenodes)), uniquenodes);cols["Canis"]<-"red"
nodes <- create_node_df(n=length(uniquenodes), nodes = seq(uniquenodes), type="number", label=uniquenodes, fillcolor=cols)
edges <- create_edge_df(from=match(df$col1, uniquenodes), to=match(df$col2, uniquenodes), rel="related")
g <-create_graph(nodes_df = nodes, edges_df = edges, attr_theme = NULL)
render_graph(g)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking exactly the same code as you used; you only need to change the definition of the nodes

```
nodes <- create_node_df(n=length(uniquenodes), nodes = seq(uniquenodes), type="number", label=uniquenodes, color=cols, style = "filled")
```

I deleted 1 parameter `fillcolor=cols` and added 2  `color=cols` and `style="filled"`.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `fillcolor`with `color` in the following line

```
nodes <- create_node_df(n=length(uniquenodes), nodes = seq(uniquenodes), type="number", label=uniquenodes, color=cols)
```